# IE11 actions.moveToElement() is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

In an specific Env. the workflow is as following:

1. Click on the "Main Menu"->Drop Down list opens
2. Click "Build" from drop down->another sub menu opens beside
3. Click "Edit" then

Now the following given selenium code is correctly executing on Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11.

```
//Main Menu opens then-->
      WebElement build = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Build"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(build);
        actions.click();
        actions.build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement edit = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit"));
       edit.click();
```

***Now problem is as follows:***
In IE11, the moveToElement(build) not actually performing. So after clicking the "Main Menu" it stops at that position only. The main menu keeps opening there but not clicking the next option that is "Build"

Answer (score 0):

Had the problem like this one

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnablePersistentHover = false;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

The key is:

```
options.EnablePersistentHover = false;
```

Regarding the problem with holding on the menu item to display child menu:

Seems, you've been using this approach:

```
WebElement edit = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit"));
edit.click();
```

Try the same. For example:

```
WebElement build = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Build"));
Thread.sleep(1000);
build.click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement edit = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit"));
edit.click();
```

After try to remove Thread::sleep rows. It is like a hardcode and you may use this approach:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Edit"));
```

Comment: If you don't mind Max, Can you tell me under which selenium package the 'InternetExplorerOptions' is there? I am using selenium 2.53 and not getting this one...

Comment: In the new env. I think the changes are made like following:

Comment: Thanks for your support. Can you help me little bit more by seeing the top solution and it consequences....

Comment: Actually do you know Max, I have used that wait.util(). But the problem is that after clicking the "Build" through the Actions the side menu is not appearing,even if I used 'clickAndHold()' for build option instead of 'click()'. Why it is not happening in IE , not very sure. I have tried just now the above said process, but the problem is same. The side menu for "Edit" is not appearning

Comment: Could you please provide HTML snippet to test?